# Pythonic idiom for this construction

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a more pythonic way of writing:

```
if value <= 10:
    print 1
elif value <= 13:
    print 2
elif value <= 15:
    print 3
elif value <= 24:
    print 4
```

The values being tested not falling into any pattern.

Comment: a  more pythonic, more clean, more readable would be suggested after you give details how you recieve input, what are logical relation between those upper bounds and printed values, etc. refactoring, clean code is verily part of software development process.

Comment: You could do `to_print = next((i for i, v in enumerate([10, 13, 15, 24], 1) if value <= v), None)` but that's just a mapping of your exact code which as @marmeladze says - is fine and readable and quite flexible if you wanted to switch to lower/upperbounds or add further criteria for each if/elif etc... So - it all depends - what do you think is wrong with your current code?

Comment: @marmeladze This is a generic problem. If you have a list of arbitrary values and you wish to perform some action depending on the value

Comment: @jonclements As you say, the code is readable, but in principle the list could get quite long. Maybe then I'd resort to a solution like yours with the values coded in sensibly named variables. The more I look at my original code, the more I like it. Clean, simple, explicit and readable

Answer (score -1):

Not sure whether this is more Pythonic, but this could be another way of doing the same thing:

```
d = {1: [float('-inf'), 10], 2: [11, 13], 3: [14, 15], 4: [16, 24]}
[print i for i in d if value >= d[i][0] and value <= d[i][1]]
```

Here you encode the lower bounds and upper bounds for each condition into the dictionary and print the key for the corresponding range that `value` is in.

Comment: Given they should be `elif`s - you don't want to build up a list for all checks - you want to shortcircuit on the first successful one

Comment: (not to mention it doesn't cater for the <= 10 criteria...)

Comment: @JonClements The first thing in the dictionary caters to the <= 10 criteria, although the lower bound for that case may be different. Moreover, the ranges are disjoint, which makes it impossible for `value` to satisfy more than one check.

Comment: Your first check includes 0 as the lower bound which isn't the same as just `<= 10` as `-7` won't meet that criteria... Also - your list-comp while it filters out only successful checks - it *runs all checks*... which an if/elif doesn't...

Comment: The first you can fix via changing `0` to `float('-inf')` however... you still should short circuit (modelling on OPs control flow) - I think the comment on the question is similar to what they're after but most of this is guess work based on what exactly the issue is the OP thinks they have with their existing code and what they're trying to do with it (if anything)

Comment: Thanks, I made the change you suggested. You're right that it would still perform all the checks. Your comment on the question is definitely more Pythonic my attempt.

Comment: You need the quotes around `-inf`... :)

Comment: Oops, missed that. Thanks, I've added them now!

Comment: Sorry Antimony, but your solution looks like a sledge-hammer to crack a nut. I was wondering if I'd missed some pythonic structure (like a dict on steroids) that would solve it. I know I could write one myself